# How to restrict recycler row in UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When recycler view is shown I need to show only first 4 list from array list. how to restrict recycler view row in android?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When passing data to your RecyclerView Adapter only include the first 4 elements.

Comment: can you explain by coding the logic?

Comment: There are many different ways to implement passing data to a RecyclerView. The answer will depend on what you currently have in place. Post your code

Comment: to adapter I m passing itemsList in get item count@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return itemsList.size} itemList is of size 10

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList.size() < 4)
        return itemsList.size();
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: if itemsList is size 10.

Comment: It will tell your recyclerview that your items collection size is 4 max. It doesn't matter that the actual size might be greater. Only first 4 will be displayed (or less if there are less than 4 elements)